# SI4T Elastic Search -- Data not being indexed

Tags: dxa, sdl-tridion, si4t, elasticsearch

I've configured SI4T using a custom elastic search from [this blog](https://velmuruganarjunan.wordpress.com/2018/09/10/tds-event-presentation-si4t-based-elasticsearch-integration-for-sdl-tridion-web-8-with-dxa-2-0/) :

After completing the tutorial. I published a page, but nothing gets added to the elastic search index.

The logs are indicating that the content is only being removed when I publish. I'm thinking it may have something to do with the TBBS but don't want to go down a rabbit hole on this. Any help is appreciated!

Here are the log messages:

```
2019-05-23 15:04:17,087 INFO  [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-47] ElasticSearchIndexer - Removing 1 documents in batches of 10

2019-05-23 15:04:17,087 INFO  [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-47] ElasticSearchIndexer - Dispatching documents in 1 batches

2019-05-23 15:04:17,087 INFO  [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-47] ElasticSearchIndexDispatcher - Removing tcm:15-1570-64 document from the elastic search Indexer

2019-05-23 15:04:17,114 INFO  [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-47] ElasticSearchIndexer - Removing 1 documents of batch 1 had the following response: Deleting 1 document(s) had the following response: OK

2019-05-23 15:04:17,114 INFO  [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-47] ElasticSearchIndexer - items to add size:  0

2019-05-23 15:04:17,114 INFO  [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-47] ElasticSearchIndexer - Clearing out registers.
```

EDIT/UPDATE :

Using the si4t search index update to SI4T TBBs provided by Sayantan Basu in combination with creating a new page and publishing did the trick.

Comment: Are you using Sites 9 by any chance?

Comment: @SayantanBasu Yes I am.

Comment: Ok then It is a known issue. already submitted the updated code but I guess it will be merge in next few days. But in the meantime, you can download the template code and manually update the class. Here are the details for reference https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/pull/21

Comment: @SayantanBasu Thank you so much for the quick response and solution! I will implement and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I updated the details in the answer.

Comment: @SayantanBasu I think your update was definitely necessary to pick up regions, but it didn't seem to solve the issue. 
Here's what I'm seeing from the logs: 2019-05-23 17:51:12,582 INFO [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-117] TridionPublishableItemProcessor - No search data found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Sites 9 Regions are newly introduced to structure the content on a page in a better way. So the page is having a new structure now. The idea is while publishing the page we need to handle this region on the SI4T template. You can find the change in the pull request https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/pull/21 . It will be merged in the next release I guess.

So either you can update it manually Or you can find it in below repository where I updated the code already and using it with Sites 9.

https://github.com/justsayantan/SI4T-develop/tree/develop/tbbs

Comment: Ouch! Can you also create a GutHub issue for the DXA Search Module for this issue?

Comment: I think your update was definitely necessary to pick up regions, but it didn't seem to solve the issue. Here's what I'm seeing from the logs:

2019-05-23 17:51:12,582 INFO  [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-117] TridionPublishableItemProcessor - No search data found.

Comment: Are you able to see the search index data while click on preview ?

Comment: In the template builder? Yes, I can see the index data being produced by the TBBs. That is what you mean right?

Comment: If you select the page and click on preview, then go to source tab and check the content, if it is there that means your updated search templates are properly working with your page template

Comment: Oh, yes I see the index data in the preview.

Comment: Can you restart the deployer service and try with fresh publishing. If you still face any issue please update the log in your question.